# Count most frequent group with Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, pandas-groupby

basically I would like to count number of the most frequent item grouped by 2 variables. I use this code:

```
dfgrouped = data[COLUMNS.copy()].groupby(['Var1','Var2']).agg(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[1])
```

This code works, but does not work on columns that have Nan values, since NaN values are float and others are str. So this error is shown:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I would like to omit NaN values and count mode for the rest. So str(x) is not a solution. And scipy.stats.mode(x, nan_policy='omit') does not work neither with an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Could you please give me an advice how to deal with that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s:

```
dfgrouped = data[COLUMNS.copy()].groupby(['Var1','Var2']).agg(lambda x: stats.mode(x.dropna())[1])
```

If need set `NaN`s for all NaNs groups:

```
dfgrouped = (data[COLUMNS.copy()]
              .groupby(['Var1','Var2'])
              .agg(lambda x: None if x.isnull().all() else stats.mode(x.dropna())[1]))
```

Comment: I do not want to remove groups with only Nan values. If this happen the mode is supposed to be null. So I tried your first help (stats.mode(x.dropna())[1]), but it works only without [1]. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

#### dropna first

You can `dropna` as an initial step before performing a `groupby`. If you attempt to `dropna` within the aggregation, then a group with all `NaN` values may  yield an error with `stats.mode`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, np.nan], [1, 2, 'hello'], [1, 2, np.nan],
                   [5, 6, 'next'], [5, 6, np.nan], [5, 6, 'next'],
                   [7, 8, np.nan], [7, 8, np.nan], [7, 8, np.nan]],
                  columns=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Value'])

res = df.dropna(subset=['Value'])\
        .groupby(['Var1', 'Var2'])\
        .agg(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[1][0])

print(res)

           Value
Var1 Var2       
1    2         1
5    6         2
```

#### catch IndexError

If you need to keep groups with all `NaN` values, then you can catch `IndexError`:

```
def mode_calc(x):
    try:
        return stats.mode(x.dropna())[1][0]
    except IndexError:
        return np.nan

res = df.groupby(['Var1', 'Var2'])\
        .agg(mode_calc)

print(res)

           Value
Var1 Var2       
1    2       1.0
5    6       2.0
7    8       NaN
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not want to remove groups with only NaN values. If this happen the mode is supposed to be null. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hta, Sure, see the alternative I've added.

Answer (score 0):

nan is of type float and np.nan == np.nan is also False. If you need to group them together, you could try something like this:

```
# First replace nan values with something like 'Unavailable'
data.fillna('Unavailable', inplace=True)
# Then re-run your code
dfgrouped = data[COLUMNS.copy()].groupby(['Var1','Var2']).agg(lambda x: stats.mode(x)[1])
```

This will group all the unavailables together as a group. Hope that helps